# How to split an 1D matrix into 4 1D sub matrices?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

To implement the Strassen Algorithm i want to split a quadratic matrix into 4 quadratic sub matrices.

The matrices are all represented as 1D-array.

```
int i, j;
int dim = 4;
int new_dim = dim / 2;

int *A = malloc(sizeof(int) * dim * dim);
//FILL A
int *a11 = malloc(sizeof(int) * new_dim * new_dim);
int *a12 = malloc(sizeof(int) * new_dim * new_dim);
int *a21 = malloc(sizeof(int) * new_dim * new_dim);
int *a22 = malloc(sizeof(int) * new_dim * new_dim);
for (i = 0; i < new_dim; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < new_dim; j++) {
        a11[i * new_dim + j] = A[XXXXX];
        a12[i * new_dim + j] = A[XXXXX];
        a21[i * new_dim + j] = A[XXXXX];
        a22[i * new_dim + j] = A[XXXXX];
    }
}
```

I dont really get what to insert for XXXXX, tried some combinations but it just does not give me the right values...

Answer (score 1):

Got it now ...

```
for (i = 0; i < new_dim; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < new_dim; j++) {
            a11[i * new_dim + j] = A[i*dim+j];
            a12[i * new_dim + j] = A[i*dim + (j+new_dim)];
            a21[i * new_dim + j] = A[(i+new_dim)*dim+j];
            a22[i * new_dim + j] = A[(i+new_dim)*dim+j+new_dim];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you so much for posting back the answer.

For all those who struggled for a day here is the 1D approach to the same problem in Java.

```
package hw8;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import static javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSize.Engineering.A;

public class matricies {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int[] A = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        //1 1 1 1 
        //2 2 2 2
        //3 3 3 3
        //4 4 4 4
        int i, j;
        int dim = 4;
        int new_dim = dim / 2;
        //int A = dim * dim;
        //FILL A
        int[] a11 = new int[new_dim * new_dim];
        int[] a12 = new int[new_dim * new_dim];
        int[] a21 = new int[new_dim * new_dim];
        int[] a22 = new int[new_dim * new_dim];

        for (i = 0; i < new_dim; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < new_dim; j++) {
                a11[i * new_dim + j] = A[i * dim + j];
                a12[i * new_dim + j] = A[i * dim + (j + new_dim)];
                a21[i * new_dim + j] = A[(i + new_dim) * dim + j];
                a22[i * new_dim + j] = A[(i + new_dim) * dim + j + new_dim];
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < a11.length; i++) {
            System.out.println ("a11: " + a11[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Red! I think you missed some formatting, could you please check?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. As you have noticed, the question asked about how to solve the problem in C. Posting an answer showing how to do it in Java, as you have done, is considered off-topic, and your answer will most likely be deleted. Please keep it in mind when you answer other questions. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexMyers Though your suggested edit, in and by itself, is a good one, I have voted to reject it. As I've just said in another comment, this kind of answer is considered off-topic here, and suggesting edits to answers that should be deleted is not encouraged.